# Update in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with my update and I can undertsand where is my mistake
So ,my table in database:place with (id,place_number,rezerv)
And I have a form:

```
<form id="formid" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post"> 
      <label>Place :</label> 
      <select name="place_number" class="place_number" id="place_number">
          <option selected="selected">-Select-</option>
      </select>
      <input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update" />
 </form>
```

And the php code:

```
   <?php
      $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "user")
    or die("Can't connect to mysql server");

$db = mysql_select_db("dt_base",$link)
    or die("Can't select database");

    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
     if($_POST['place_number'])
     {
      $place_number = $_POST['place_number'];
  mysql_query("UPDATE place SET rezerv = 1 WHERE place_number = '$place_number'",$link);
      }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: There is no value in your `<option>`

Comment: update is not in the database..

Comment: Unrelated to your question: [DO NOT use `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and [sanitize your inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: @CompuChip `mysqli` bla bla bla.. always theres someone.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your form field:

```
<select name="place_number" class="place_number" id="place_number">
      <option selected="selected">-Select-</option>
      <option value="1" selected="selected">Place 1</option>
      <option value="2" selected="selected">Place 2</option>
  </select>
```

And then try again.

Comment: I need to populate the select box with date from database?

Comment: We don't know where you get your data from. But if you want the user to select a place number you will have to put some data in the dropdown, right?

Comment: Like this:  $sql=mysql_query("select id,place_number from place");
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                  $id=$row['id'];
                  $place_number=$row['place_number'];
                  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$place_number.'</option>';

    }

Comment: Yes. Like that. I would like to note that the use of the mysql_query is very old and soon to be abolished. I'd suggest you step over to mysqli(basically the same) or PDO for your queries.